# Computer won't start unless power is removed for ~2 hours

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power, diagnostic

About 6 months ago I built myself a desktop. A few weeks ago the computer started to act strange, for example it wouldn't always give a video signal when it came out of sleep.

Now the issue has become persistent. I can start the PC and it works fine, but if i shut it down and start it up again it wouldn't give video output. The power LED and fans are running, but it never boots. No video signal, no post screen: nothing. When i leave the power off for like one night it would start the following day without any problems. It seems like it needs to discharge before it runs normal?

Anyway, it seems like capacitors are broken (like mentioned here: [Computer won't start unless power is removed for ~5 minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/228176/computer-wont-start-unless-power-is-removed-for-5-minutes?newreg=1a8c8575b5354e91ad3128e1c986bac3)). But I can't really figure out if its the motherboard or PSU? I do not see or hear any abnormalities on my motherboard/PSU. What should be the defective component?

Comment: Do you have others PSU units to test with?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I would say it's your PSU. If you can (meaning that the unit isn't under any warranty), carefully, open it up and inspect it, maybe it needs some cleaning. For example, I clean mine PSU once every 6 months.

Comment: I suppose cleaning the PS makes it seem like you're doing something, but it's not going to fix this problem.  A long shot might be to replace any "coin" battery that may be on the motherboard, but a problem with the reset line seems more likely.  I don't recall whether the reset is generated out of the PS or off the MB in current designs.

Comment: A reset is purely a software command processed by the motherboard, not the power supply. You could have a bad motherboard, video card, or even some other component. Try removing everything that's non-essential (add-on cards, etc.) and see if the behavior changes. You should make sure you're running the latest BIOS version, and at some point you'll have no choice but to try a different video card and power supply.

Comment: So what you're saying is that this couldn't be an PSU failing? I did strip anything out the PC. The CPU has an APU (AMD A10), but trying an external GPU didn't help either. I dont have an other PSU laying around. I also did remove the battery from the motherboard but this didn't help either.

Comment: @Twisty - "Reset" is an electrical signal, generated as the power supply voltage rises.  It's what assures that the motherboard and other components start up properly,  I just can't recall whether the logic to generate it is in the power supply or on the motherboard.

Comment: @DanielRHicks My mistake, I think we're talking about different things. I was referring to a physical reset switch which would be electrically connected to the motherboard (my very loose use of *software command* didn't help either).  Carry on!

Comment: @user1226868 You really do need to try another power supply, because if that doesn't solve the problem (noting you've now tried another graphics card) you're looking at much greater odds that your motherboard is to blame.

Comment: I'm going to send the PSU for RMA, i will keep you guys updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out to be the PSU! I bought a new one and it fixed the problem, permanently.